# How can I make a mirror image of an existing matrix?

Tags: r, matrix, mirror

I currently have a matrix that only shows half of the responses, I would like the ID's in the table to be both vertical and horizontal with their corresponding results.

What my data looks like

```
ID
1  0
2  1 0
3  1 2 0
4  4 2 1 0
5  2 1 2 1 0
```

I have not been able to find any code that could help me do this.

I would like it to look like this.

```
ID
   1 2 3 4 5
1  0 1 1 4 2 
2  1 0 2 2 1
3  1 2 0 1 2
4  4 2 1 0 1
5  2 1 2 1 0
```

So that each ID is represented vertically and horizontally.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: similar to @d.b, you can use `m[upper.tri(m)]=t(m)[upper.tri(t(m))]`

Comment: How does your data look like that in the first place? Can you share a `dput()`? I didn't thing a matrix would just have a blank section like that.

Comment: @MrFlick, I'm guessing `dist`. If so, you just need `m <- as.matrix(d)`.

Comment: @Axeman good call. That’s probably it.

Comment: @d.b or @boski could you elaborate further.  I have tried to reproduce my desired outcome with your code and I have gotten a few errors (Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, list, value = c("2", "3", "4", "5", : 'value' is the wrong length) or the outcome is not what I expected.

Comment: @T.McMillen, your error suggests you have a data.frame, not a matrix. It would really help if you'd follow MrFlick's suggestion and `dput()` your object.